# redux array not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In redux I  have an array of `selectedItems` and `changedItems`

`selectedItems: ["element 0","element 1","element 2"]`

`changedItems: ["element 6","element 7","element 8"]`

`<Button onClick={() => this.props.addItem(this.props.changedItems)}>save</Button>`

I have a button that fires the `addItem` action but this is pushing 1 element into the `selectedItems` array from the `changedItems` array instead of all 3 elements and also I would like it to completely remove any existing elements in the `selectedItems` array when this is done

How can I push all elements from the `changedItems` array into the `selectedItems` array and overwrite the existing items in the `selectedItems` array?

**actions.js**

```
export const addItem = (item) => ({
  type: ADD_ITEM,
  item,
})

export const removeItem = (item) => ({
  type: REMOVE_ITEM,
  item,
})

export const clearItems = () => ({
  type: CLEAR_ITEMS,
})


export const addChangedItem = (item) => ({
  type: ADD_CHANGED_ITEM,
  item,
})

export const removeChangedItem = (item) => ({
  type: REMOVE_CHANGED_ITEM,
  item,
})
```

**selectedItemReducer.js**

```
import {
  ADD_ITEM, CLEAR_ITEMS, REMOVE_ITEM,
} from '../Constants'

const selectedItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.item,
      ]
    case REMOVE_ITEM:
      return state.filter((item) => item !== action.item)
    case CLEAR_ITEMS:
      return []
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default selectedItemReducer
```

**changedItemReducer.js**

```
import {
  ADD_CHANGED_ITEM, REMOVE_CHANGED_ITEM,
} from '../Constants'

const changedItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CHANGED_ITEM:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.item,
      ]
    case REMOVE_CHANGED_ITEM:
      return state.filter((item) => item !== action.item)
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default changedItemReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

If `changedItems` is guaranteed to always be an array, you should return those values in the reducer. From the looks of your `changedItemReducer` this appears to be the case.

```
const selectedItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return action.item;
    case REMOVE_ITEM:
      return state.filter((item) => item !== action.item)
    case CLEAR_ITEMS:
      return []
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

If not always an array then check first. If an array, return it, if not an array, place item into an array and return it.

```
const selectedItemReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return Array.isArray(action.item) ? action.item : [item];
    case REMOVE_ITEM:
      return state.filter((item) => item !== action.item)
    case CLEAR_ITEMS:
      return []
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In both cases you are "throwing away" the old state when saving (returning) the new "changed items".